# cPanel scanning script error when comparing two variables: [: : integer expression expected

Tags: bash, variable, test

I'm trying to implement real time scanning on cPanel server.

When I use the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash
#Maximum file size to scan in bytes that's set to 10MB
MAXSIZE=10485760
if [ "$UPLOAD_SIZE" -le "$MAXSIZE" ]; then
/usr/bin/clamdscan --remove --quiet --no-summary "$1"
fi
```

Output shows,

```
line 4: [: : integer expression expected
```

Comment: Bash has `((...))` for arithmetics. Use `if ((upload_size < maxsize)); then ...; fi`  Also don't use `UPPERCASE` for normal variable names.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like your $UPLOAD_SIZE is unset (or empty or non-numeric), that's why you get an error. What you probably want is declaring it before comparing if it is lesser than something, which you haven't done.